# Checkboxes/Radio Buttons- Adding price total of chosen item

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with radio buttons and checkboxes. In this example project I have radio buttons and checkboxes displaying an image based on the value that is chosen by a user.

How can I add a value price to each item chosen and display total cost at the bottom? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

The js below shows the process in which I am displaying the images based on the value chosen.

**JS**

```
<script>
function check_value(currentElement, val, id, type) {
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val > 0 && val < 4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]

        if(currentElement.checked)
        {
            el.src = "images/" + type + val + ".jpg";
            el.style.display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            el.src = "";
            el.style.display = "none";
        }           
    }
}    
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
<form name="builder">
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 1, 1, "bike")'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F- $8,399<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 2, 1, "bike")'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S- $13,090<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 3, 1, "bike")'/> Aprilia RSV4- $16,999<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox1" src="#" style="display:none"> 

<h2>Choose a tire</h2>  
<form name="tire">
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 1, 2, "tire")'/> Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires- $299.99<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 2, 2, "tire")'/> Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires- $154.99<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 3, 2, "tire")'/> Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires- $119.99<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox2" src="#" style="display:none">

<h2>Choose Accesories</h2>
<form name="tire">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 1, "3a", "accessories")'/> Chrome Front Plate- $246.50<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 2, "3b", "accessories")'/> Jacket- $87.99<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" onclick='check_value(this, 3, "3c", "accessories")'/> Gloves- $35.99            
</form>

<div id="accessories">
    <img id="imgBox3a" src="#" style="display:none">
    <img id="imgBox3b" src="#" style="display:none">
    <img id="imgBox3c" src="#" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start to

1. **remove unnecessary formTags** and reduce it down to **one**.
2. Change input names (eg: "cylces" and "tire" for radios and "frontPlate" see code below).
3. correct function *(reduce params)* and set price as value attribut of input fields
4. add `for-loop` to *calculate current total*

Here we are ...

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function check_value(curElem, id) {
            var el = document.getElementById("img" + curElem.name);
            el.src = "images/" + curElem.name + id + ".jpg";
            if (!curElem.checked)
                el.style.display = "none";
            else
                el.style.display = "block";

            // calculate Total
            var total = 0;
            var controls = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                if ((controls[i].type === 'radio' || controls[i].type === 'checkbox') && controls[i].checked)
                    total = total + parseFloat(controls[i].value);
            }
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
            //alert("Total: " + total);
        }    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="builder">
        <h2>
            Choose a bike</h2>
        <input type="radio" name="Bike" value="8399" onclick='check_value(this, 1)' />
        KAWASAKI KX 450F- $8,399<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Bike" value="13090" onclick='check_value(this, 2)' />
        2010 Yamaha Road Star S- $13,090<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Bike" value="16999" onclick='check_value(this, 3)' />
        Aprilia RSV4- $16,999<br />
        <img id="imgBike" src="#" style="display: none" />
        <h2>
            Choose a tire</h2>
        <input type="radio" name="Tire" value="299.99" onclick='check_value(this, 1)' />
        Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires- $299.99<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Tire" value="154.99" onclick='check_value(this, 2)' />
        Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires- $154.99<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Tire" value="119.99" onclick='check_value(this, 3)' />
        Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires- $119.99<br />
        <img id="imgTire" src="#" style="display: none" />
        <h2>
            Choose Accesories</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="FrontPlate" value="246.50" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />
        Chrome Front Plate- $246.50<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="Jacket" value="87.90" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />
        Jacket- $87.99<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="Gloves"  value="35.99" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />
        Gloves- $35.99
        <div id="accessories">
            <img id="imgFrontPlate" src="#" style="display: none" />
            <img id="imgJacket" src="#" style="display: none" />
            <img id="imgGloves" src="#" style="display: none" />
        </div>
        <div id="total"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

*Although* this *might be a solution* to your answer - I don't see the use of this code. In a real life environment **most of the data will come from a server generated** so you will have to **completely re-do this code**!

Comment: +1 Thank you! Is there away to have the image appear first before the alert? or instead of having the result appear in alert let it show in text inside a `div`?